# Understanding the bigger picture of Android Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have recently started to learn how to develop an Android Application and have been reading the official documentation from Android. After reading the section on `Intents`, some questions popped into my head and I was unable to find an answer on Google.

The first question is that an `Intent` seems to discourage developers from reinventing the wheel, is that the correct mindset to have? Many Android applications seem to have similar functions such as taking a picture with the camera on the phone. Using the `Intent` with the correct configurations can allow access to functionality of other components (such as the Camera app).

The second question that I have is about explicit `Intents`. From what I understand after reading about explicit `Intents`, it seems that an app developer has access to certain functionality if they know the fully qualified name of the class (which includes the package name). What is stopping one developer from guessing the fully classified class names and using functionality of another app that wasn't meant to be shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct on the first question.  If your app needs to allow the user to take a photo, look something up on a map, edit a contact, etc., why go through the trouble of implementing those functions yourself when you could pass it off to another app that can do what you want and then return the data back to you?

As for question two.. If you don't register your intent via an intent filter in your manifest file then other apps won't be able to access your activities.  For example, you can build a web browser app, but if you don't register the intent, the system won't see it as an app that is capable of web browsing and therefore won't offer your app as an option to the user when they click on a link somewhere.